# Does anyone cook/eat bladders?

Tags: offal

There's a few places in the world that really don't waste any part of an animal when it comes to cooking, but I've yet to see any form of cooked bladders.

Is it an item that is cooked -or- eaten anywhere in the world?

Comment: I think I remember seeing somewhere that it's used as a "package" for stuffing, similar to how stomach is used for haggis. Can't point to the cuisine though.

Comment: Haggis can also be made with the bladder. Like all "poor" food, it's more about the technique than it is about the specific recipe. The bladder obviously requires more cleaning than the stomach because of the strong smell associated with it, but any natural pouch can be used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  [Here's a specific example](http://www.fourpoundsflour.com/travelogue-chickens-cooked-in-bladders/).  Asian cuisine also has a [strong tradition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offal#Asia) of using a wide variety of organ meats, many of which are considered delicacies.

The bladder would be a particularly tough piece of protein to prepare, but you can make just about anything palatable with proper cleaning and a long braise.

Comment: I don't actually see any culinary examples on the Wikipedia page, and the specific example isn't really about cooking/eating the bladders but rather using them as a vessel, from which the portion intended for eating is subsequently *removed*. So it's not even like a sausage casing - it's "cooked" in more or less the same way that aluminum foil is "cooked" when used for braising. Based on the pictures in your first link, the bladders themselves look quite inedible.

Comment: @Aaronut Very true; there may be a specific culinary or non-english term for bladder which I'm not finding.  However, the bladder has demonstrable culinary use, and there are specific examples of similarly tough cuts like stomach being used.  I personally have had (and greatly enjoyed!) dishes with tripe and tendon, which take a lot of cooking and still remain quite chewy.  I think the hardest part of preparing the bladder would be cleaning, which is quite challenging with other cuts like stomach.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know how they use it, but I live in the Czech Republic (I’m American) and they sell chicken bladder here.